# How to delete pull request from recent activities in bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

I tried to delete the pull request by declinig it, but it still can be seen in recent activities.HOw to delete it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't currently possible to remove individual items from the recent activities feed, though you can push that pull request off the list by performing new activities.

Also worth mentioning here: the "Pull Requests" link in that repo will continue to list your declined pull request if you set the filter to "Declined".